# DeviceIoControl call fails with windows error code 183

Tags: c#, windows, ioctl, iscsi

I am trying to write buffer data to SCSI device, but when I fire the deviceIoControl call, I get the windows error code 183. The error code indicates File already exits but I am not able to understand the error with respect to the IOCTL call.

The CreateFile function passed as i was able to get the appropriate device Handle as shown below.

int devHandle = DeviceIoControlHelper.CreateFile(
                       deviceName,
                       DeviceIoControlHelper.GENERIC_READ | DeviceIoControlHelper.GENERIC_WRITE,
                       DeviceIoControlHelper.FILE_SHARE_READ | DeviceIoControlHelper.FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                       IntPtr.Zero,
                       DeviceIoControlHelper.OPEN_EXISTING,
                       0,
                       IntPtr.Zero);

However, when i try to write the buffer I get the error :

```
 dwReturned = 0;
        int b = DeviceIoControlHelper.DeviceIoControl(
                devHandle,
                DeviceIoControlHelper.IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH,
                inpBuffer,
                (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(info),
                inpBuffer, //out pDriveLayout,
                (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(info), //(uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX)),
                out dwReturned,
                IntPtr.Zero);

        Log.Write(Log.TraceLevel_5,"ExecuteDeviceIoControl return pass_through scsistatus = " + info.spt.ScsiStatus);
        if (b == 0)
        {
            int win_err = this.GetWindowsErrorCode();
            Log.Write(Log.TraceLevel_5, "ExecuteDeviceIoControl failed, error =  " + win_err);
            LogMyTrace.Write(LogMyTrace.TraceLevel_5, "ExecuteDeviceIoControl failed, error =  " + win_err);

            this.CloseOpenHandle(devHandle);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(inpBuffer);
            throw new Exception("DeviceIoControl  failed " + deviceName +
                    " is '" + deviceName + "'. Windows Err is " + win_err);
        }
The error code is 183.
```

Please provide some inputs as why this error is being caused and the soultion.

I am using Windows 2008 R2 (x64) and it is the iSCSI path.